Ipython: Slide a slider --> change text in a pdf
In the self-contained IPython/Jupyter code below, you drag a slider and the text in the pdf should change -- the pdf text should be regenerated when you release the mouse button.
I see the slider. I see the pdf if I uncomment the final line -- so the pdf generation is working. However when I try to put that final line inside the "update" function, the pdf doesn't show up! So I can't see the pdf if I call it from inside the "update" function. Any ideas?
%reset -f
import os
import subprocess
from ipywidgets import interact, IntSlider

class pdf(object):
  def __init__(self, pdf, size=(200,200)):
    self.pdf = pdf
    self.size = size
  def _repr_html_(self):
    return '<iframe src={0} width={1[0]} height={1[1]}></iframe>'.format(self.pdf, self.size)
  def _repr_latex_(self):
    return r'\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{{{0}}}'.format(self.pdf)

def update(x=1):
    content = r'''\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    Slider value is: %d
    \end{document}'''
    with open('cover.tex','w') as f:
        f.write(content % x)
    cmd = ['pdflatex', '-interaction', 'nonstopmode', 'cover.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()
    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink('cover.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Error {} executing command: {}'.format(retcode, ' '.join(cmd)))
    os.unlink('cover.tex')
    os.unlink('cover.log')
    pdf('cover.pdf', size=(300,250))

interact(update, x=IntSlider(min=0, max=10, continuous_update=False));

#pdf('cover.pdf',size=(300,250)) # If you uncomment this line, you see the pdf. But it doesn't update with the slider because it's not inside the "update" function!

